# jqxGrid server side filter working wrong

Tags: jquery, datagrid, asp-classic, jqxgrid, jqwidget

I have a large table and I am using [jqxGrid](http://kirsehirilan.net/paging/filter.asp). Paging and sorting very well. But filters working strange.

If I firstly select first column, and then typing 2nd column and then typing 3rd column, it works fine. But I firstly typing 3rd column, it filters first column.

My asp codes which get filter variables:

```
filterValue0 = Left((Request.QueryString("filtervalue0")),1)
filterValue1 = Request.QueryString("filtervalue1")
filterValue2 = Request.QueryString("filtervalue2")
```

My filtering codes:

```
filter: function(){
$("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('updatebounddata', 'filter');
},
```

How should I take variables for working fine.

Thanks for your helps…

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem myself.

```
filtervalue0 = Request.QueryString("filtervalue0")
filtervalue1 = Request.QueryString("filtervalue1")
filtervalue2 = Request.QueryString("filtervalue2")

filterdata0 = Request.QueryString("filterdatafield0")
filterdata1 = Request.QueryString("filterdatafield1")
filterdata2 = Request.QueryString("filterdatafield2")
```

SQL code:

```
SQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE Grup = 1 "
If Len(filtervalue0) <> 0 Then SQL = SQL + "AND "&filterdata0&" LIKE '%" + filterValue0 + "%'" 
If Len(filtervalue1) <> 0 Then SQL = SQL + "AND "&filterdata1&" LIKE '%" + filterValue1 + "%'" 
If Len(filtervalue2) <> 0 Then SQL = SQL + "AND "&filterdata2&" LIKE '%" + filterValue2 + "%'" 
SQL = SQL + " ORDER BY "&Sirala&" "&SiralaYon
SayfaRS.Open SQL, Conn
```